# awk for different scenarios

Tags: bash, awk

I am currently trying to work up a solution that generates strings based on the input.

When I execute the function

```
cat text | awk '{printf("%s global\n", $1);}'
```

in which text is

```
0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1 NO NO NO NO YES YES YES YES
```

and the output is

```
0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1 global
```

which is correct, but in some cases the text can be

```
K_0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1 NO NO NO NO YES YES YES YES
```

in which case the following command, would not work, as the output should be

```
K_0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1 Kai
```

how do i make `awk` know when it should output Kai or global?

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional `print`:

```
awk '{print $1, ($1 ~ /^K_/ ? "Kai" : "global")}' file

0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1 global
K_0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1 Kai
```

Comment: Perfect that works.. I knew there would be a simple solution thanks :)